# How to override gutenberg paragraph block edit property

Tags: plugin-development, block-editor

I want to change gutenberg core paragraph block.
My exact problem is...
I need to count the characters of the first paragraph. If the number is greater than the specified number, add a class to that paragraph. Basically when user types more than specified word count the paragraph change to orange color. Is that possible?

I know there is some way to extend blocks but I don't want to change the title or add some attribute. I need to change the paragraph(Richtext or Plaintext editor) edit property (using the onchange event). How is that possible?

Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

EDIT:

```
( function ( blocks, element, blockEditor ) {
    
    var el = wp.element.createElement;
    const { RichText } = blockEditor;
 
    var withInspectorControls = wp.compose.createHigherOrderComponent( function (
        BlockEdit
    ) {
        console.log('Working...');
        return function ( props ) {
            function onChangeContent( newContent ) {
                console.log('Working...');
            }
            return el(
                RichText,
                {
                    tagName: 'p',
                    format: 'string',
                    className: 'avijit-subscription-block-title',
                    onChange: onChangeContent,
                    value: props.attributes.content,
                    formattingControls: [ 'bold' ]
                }
            );
        };
    },
    'withInspectorControls' );
    
    wp.hooks.addFilter(
        'editor.BlockEdit',
        'core/paragraph',
        withInspectorControls
    );

} )( window.wp.blocks, window.wp.element, window.wp.blockEditor );
```

Comment: Can you share any code that you've tried?

Comment: The onChange event is working fine but how to change the paragraph class when it exceeds 100 characters? Thank you

Comment: The code as it stands is completely replacing the paragraph block which is not what the `editor.BlockEdit` filter is intended for. In this case, you don't need an `onChange` handler. `core/paragraph`'s current value is stored as the `content` attribute, and the HOC you're adding through to the `editor.BlockEdit` filter is executed each time the attributes change - the whole function is pretty much acting like an `onChange` handler. I think you can do this without modifying or adding block components at all... I'll give it a run a little later

Comment: Thanks for reply. Can please explain where to insert the code to add class of that paragraph when it exceeds 100 characters.